# How to combine Filtering, Grouping, and Sorting in Kendo UI Vue Grid (native)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-vue

I'm trying to enable some operations on my grid such as grouping, filtering and sorting, individually they works as shown in the docs but there is no an example of those functionality working together.

By myself I was able to combine sorting and filtering but grouping does not work when i'm adding it as it shown in the docs. look at at my code

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Grid :style="{height: '100%'}"
        ref="grid"
        :data-items="getData"
        :resizable="true"
        :reorderable="true"
        @columnreorder="columnReorder"
        :filterable="true"
        :filter="filter"
        @filterchange="filterChange"
        :sortable="true"
        :sort= "sort"
        @sortchange="sortChangeHandler"
        :groupable="true"
        :group= "group"
        @dataStateChange="dataStateChange"
        :columns="columns">
    </Grid>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        items: [],
        editID: null,
        columns: [
         { field: 'AbsenceEmployeID', filterable:false, editable: false, title: '#'},
         { field: 'Employe', title: 'Employer', cell: DropDownEmployes},
         { field: 'Remarque', title: 'Remarque'},
         { field: 'Type', title: 'Type', cell: DropDownTypes},
         { field: 'CreatedDate', filter:'date', editable: false, editor: 'date', title: 'créé le', format: '{0:d}'},
         { title: 'Actions', filterable:false, cell: CommandCell}
        ],
        filter: {
          logic: "and",
          filters: []
        },
        sort: [
          { field: 'CreatedDate', dir: 'desc' }
        ],
        group: [],
        gridData: []
      }
    }
    mounted() { 
      this.loadItems()
    },
    computed: {
      absencesList() {
        return this.items.map((item) => Object.assign({ inEdit: item.AbsenceEmployeID === this.editID}, item));
     },
     getData() {
       return orderBy(filterBy(this.absencesList, this.filter), this.sort);
     },
     ...mapState({
       absences: state => state.absences.absences
      })
    }
    methods: {
      loadItems () {
        this.$store.dispatch('absences/getAbsences')
          .then(resp => {
            this.items = this.absences.map(item => item)
          })
      },
      filterChange: function(ev) {
       this.filter = ev.filter;
      },
      columnReorder: function(options) {
        this.columns = options.columns;
      },
      sortChangeHandler: function(e) {
        this.sort = e.sort;
      },

      // the following is for grouping but not yet used, read more
      groupedData: function () {
        this.gridData = process(this.getData, {group: this.group});
      },
      createAppState: function(dataState) {
        this.group = dataState.group;
        this.groupedData();
      },
      dataStateChange: function (event) {
        this.createAppState(event.data);
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

The last three methods are not used yet, so filtering and sorting is working perfectly as of now. then in other to enable grouping I want to replace `:data-items="getData"` by `:data-items="gridData"` and run `this.groupedData()` method after the items are loaded but grouping doesn't work.
I think everything should be handle by the `dataStateChange` event and `process()` function but I also tried but without success

Answer (score 0):

If you define the *filterchange* and *sortchange* events they are being triggered for filter and sort and you will have to updated data in their handlers. If you rather want to use *datastatechage* event for all the changes you have to remove the *filterchange* and *sortchange* events and the *datastatechage* event will be triggered instead of them. In this case you will have to update the data in its handler.

You can use the process method of @progress/kendo-data-query by passing the respective parameter each data change that is needed as in the example below:

```
const result = process(data, {
    skip: 10,
    take: 20,
    group: [{
      field: 'category.categoryName',
            aggregates: [
                  { aggregate: "sum", field: "unitPrice" },
                  { aggregate: "sum", field: "unitsInStock" }
            ]
      }],
    sort: [{ field: 'productName', dir: 'desc' }],
    filter: {
        logic: "or",
        filters: [
          { field: "discontinued", operator: "eq", value: true },
          { field: "unitPrice", operator: "lt", value: 22 }
        ]
    }
});
```

Hers is a sample stackblitz example where such example is working correctly - https://stackblitz.com/edit/3ssy1k?file=index.html

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'm using edit like in this [example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid-native/editing/), the thing here is that my grid should read data from computed property in other open and close the edit field. so how to implement this with process()

Comment: The Grid native seems not stable

Comment: In such cases when both editing and sorting is used it may be quite tricky to use a computed property for the gridData so I would rather recommend updating the data manually when you need so you could have a more precise control. Here is an example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/jcevsc-qniu5x?file=index.js. Also would you please elaborate what do you mean it is not stable and why you think so?

Comment: Every examples for grouping is not working on my environment, I've even updated my node.js and npm. I've also tried on a fresh vue.js project. Grouping is not working at all

Comment: I tried to reproduce the same example that was given on the docs and also the one you provided to me. All of them react the same way

Comment: It is not clear what is not working correctly and what is your environment - would you please elaborate that. Here is how it works at my side with the code from the demo https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid-native/grouping/ - https://www.screencast.com/t/vL6CcFy1F. Another option is to submit a question with full the explanation to the Telerik team in their form - https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-ui-vue

Comment: I finally found the solution today the event we are supposed to listen to is v-on:datastatechange  and not v-on:dataStateChange

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the **groupchange** method to handle Grouping

I prefer to use process from @progress/kendo-data-query

The following is a complete example of this

```
<template>
<Grid :style="{height: height}"
      :data-items="gridData"
      :skip="skip"
      :take="take"
      :total="total"
      :pageable="pageable"
      :page-size="pageSize"
      :filterable="true"
      :filter="filter"
      :groupable="true"
      :group="group"
      :sortable="true"
      :sort="sort"
      :columns="columns"
      @sortchange="sortChangeHandler"
      @pagechange="pageChangeHandler"
      @filterchange="filterChangeHandler"
      @groupchange="groupChangeHandler"
/>
</template>

<script>
import '@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css';
import { Grid } from '@progress/kendo-vue-grid';
import { process } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';

const sampleProducts = [
{
    'ProductID': 1,
    'ProductName': 'Chai',
    'UnitPrice': 18,
    'Discontinued': false,
},
{
    'ProductID': 2,
    'ProductName': 'Chang',
    'UnitPrice': 19,
    'Discontinued': false,
},
{
    'ProductID': 3,
    'ProductName': 'Aniseed Syrup',
    'UnitPrice': 10,
    'Discontinued': false,
},
{
    'ProductID': 4,
    'ProductName': "Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning",
    'UnitPrice': 22,
    'Discontinued': false,
},
];

export default {
components: {
    Grid,
},
data () {
    return {
        gridData: sampleProducts,
        filter: {
            logic: 'and',
            filters: [],
        },
        skip: 0,
        take: 10,
        pageSize: 5,
        pageable: {
            buttonCount: 5,
            info: true,
            type: 'numeric',
            pageSizes: true,
            previousNext: true,
        },
        sort: [],
        group: [],
        columns: [
            { field: 'ProductID', filterable: false, title: 'Product ID', width: '130px' },
            { field: 'ProductName', title: 'Product Name' },
            { field: 'UnitPrice', filter: 'numeric', title: 'Unit Price' },
            { field: 'Discontinued', filter: 'boolean', title: 'Discontinued' },
        ],
    };
},
computed: {
    total () {
        return this.gridData ? this.gridData.length : 0;
    },
},
mounted () {
    this.getData();
},
methods: {
    getData: function () {
        this.gridData = process(sampleProducts,
            {
                skip: this.skip,
                take: this.take,
                group: this.group,
                sort: this.sort,
                filter: this.filter,
            });
    },
    // ------------------Sorting------------------
    sortChangeHandler: function (event) {
        this.sort = event.sort;
        this.getData();
    },
    // ------------------Paging------------------
    pageChangeHandler: function (event) {
        this.skip = event.page.skip;
        this.take = event.page.take;
        this.getData();
    },
    // ------------------Filter------------------
    filterChangeHandler: function (event) {
        this.filter = event.filter;
        this.getData();
    },
    // ------------------Grouping------------------
    groupChangeHandler: function (event) {
        this.group = event.group;
        this.getData();
    },
},
};
</script>
```